# Control does not immediately return to first row in UITableView after dismissing UIImageView in iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, uitextfield

I have an iOS application where I am displaying a UITableView, which in turn is composed of custom rows that are made up of UITextFields, and UILabels.  On first launch, I have a UIImageView that covers the UITableView until the user presses a button in order to dismiss the UIImageView (thus revealing the UITableView behind it).

However, my problem is that instead of returning control to the first row of the UITableView, it is selecting the last row of the UITableView, and on top of that, despite me making an explicit call to the method, "becomeFirstResponder", the UITextField in the last row of the UITableView does not allow me to enter text until I explicitly select a row from the table.  Then and only then am I able to enter text.  I am assuming that my method "cellForRowAtIndexPath" populates my table from the top down, which is why the last row of the table is being selected, and not the top (this is my guess, and if I am wrong please correct me).

What I would like to do is enable the very first row of the UITableView once the user dismisses the UIImageView AND have it become the "firstResponder" automatically, allowing the user to enter text right away without having to explicitly select a particular row.

My code that dismisses the UIImageView after pressing a button is here:

```
- (IBAction)beginDataEntry:(id)sender {
    
    [_imageView removeFromSuperview];
    [_cell.dataField becomeFirstResponder];
    
}
```

It is as if my UITableView is in a "limbo" state until I explicitly select a row from the table.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add more code, like how are you creating your table view?

Comment: I create my UITableView in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Use UITableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated: to display the correct row when the view is redisplayed.

It is always safer to use index paths to refer to table rows rather than keeping references to cells.  So, here's an alternative:

```
- (IBAction)beginTireCountEntry:(id)sender {

    [_imageView removeFromSuperview];
    NSIndexPath firstCellPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
     [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath: firstCellPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
    MyCell cell = (MyCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:firstCellPath];
    [cell.dataField becomeFirstResponder];

}
```